# iOS multitasking closing is poorly designed?

Tags: buttons, ios, close

I have a question about iOS's multitasking bar, and a design decision in it. If you double tap the homescreen to go into the multitasking bar(http://cdn.imacify.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/10/IMG_0628.png) holding down your finger on one of the apps will bring up the "shaking close UI" for lack of a better term (http://cdn.imacify.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/10/IMG_0629.png), this is consistent with the homescreen which is great, but my issue is the size of the close button is so incredibly small that I usually have to try two or three times to get the button (I have big fingers) if you tap one of the apps (not the x) nothing happens and the "shaking close UI" is still in effect, literally nothing happens, why not have it so that tapping the app's icon, closes it, this would be much easier for the user, and wouldn't remove any functionality as the button doesn't do anything anyways. The same goes for deleting apps on the homescreen, although I do understand that a little more, because deleting an app, as opposed to closing it, is a much more deliberate, and permanent action. Is there any reasoning behind this UX design choice? Is it bad software engineering/an accident? Or just a bad choice by engineers?

Comment: This isn't a question that you need an answer to, it's more of a rant disguised as a question - something mentioned in [our FAQ as something not to ask here](http://ux.stackexchange.com/faq#dontask) as its not a constructive question.

Comment: My question is almost analogous to: http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/34650/what-reason-could-nintendo-have-had-for-putting-the-a-and-b-buttons-the-wrong-wa , and that question was never closed

Answer (score 2):

Those are not running apps they are recent run apps.  Apple refers to them as "recently used apps" [here](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht4211). Further expressed in [this article](http://speirs.org/blog/2012/1/2/misconceptions-about-ios-multitasking.html).

So removing things from this list is hardly ever necessary.  Nevertheless, should you want to remove them it should be doable without frustration. All in all wouldn't call it *bad* design.  Maybe *mediocre* design.

Comment: I thought that these where running apps, and have been told by my kids to close them often since they drain battery. I guess their statement is false?

Comment: After reading that page, apple is seeming to imply that not all apps take advantage of multitasking, I'm assuming there's some sort of multitasking API for iOS that you have to take advantage of for system resources to be taken up, and apple is clarifying that this doesn't mean all software, will not forget where you left off.